# How to get a running normalized column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, normalize

I am trying to make a new column with the proportion of the whole, grouping by the "category" and "conservation_status" column. I am not sure if "normalize" is the correct term because after looking at some other posts, it's not same result that I am trying to achieve.

Here is a screenshot of my current dataset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hh2x.png)

In this image I have can explain better the problem I'm trying to solve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNIfq.png)

So for each row in the count column, I would like to divide it by the sum of counts for that category.

```
#species_df dataframe

{'category': {0: 'Mammal', 1: 'Mammal', 2: 'Mammal', 3: 'Mammal', 4: 'Mammal'},
 'scientific_name': {0: 'Clethrionomys gapperi gapperi',
  1: 'Bos bison',
  2: 'Bos taurus',
  3: 'Ovis aries',
  4: 'Cervus elaphus'},
 'common_names': {0: "Gapper's Red-Backed Vole",
  1: 'American Bison, Bison',
  2: 'Aurochs, Aurochs, Domestic Cattle (Feral), Domesticated Cattle',
  3: 'Domestic Sheep, Mouflon, Red Sheep, Sheep (Feral)',
  4: 'Wapiti Or Elk'},
 'conservation_status': {0: 'None',
  1: 'None',
  2: 'None',
  3: 'None',
  4: 'None'}}
```

For example I am looking to create "new_column" adjacent "count", for the *Amphibian* "category".

| count | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .01 |
| 73 | .91 |
| 4 | .05 |
| 2 | .03 |

I have tried:

```
species_df.groupby(['category', 'conservation_status']).scientific_name.count() / species_df.groupby('category').scientific_name.count()
```

It returns:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

I was thinking something similar to SQL Window functions, but I just can't get around this one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `GroupBy.count` is an aggregating operation, you might find `.transform("count")` which is a transformation (keeps the same shape as input df) more helpful. Please add the data in a reproducible format if you would like more help

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try transform. What do you mean by "a reproducible format",  I'm new to using this site. Thanks again

Comment: @KeithTaylor a reproducible format means formatted text for `species_df` rather than a screenshot of your jupyter notebook cell. if you can copy and paste the output from `species_df.head().to_dict()` directly into your question, then people will be able to run your commands, thanks!